# Using LINQ to compare two sequences for differences

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm comparing two enumerables of different types, but seeing if there's any differences between them.  I do this by casting them both to an enumerable list of compatible anonymous types:

```
var curCombo = (from c in curPlan.TPM_TRAININGPLANSOLUTIONS orderby c.TASKID select new { Id = c.TASKID, Marker = c.ISMARKERCOMPLETION });
var newCombo = (from c in plan.Combo orderby c.TaskId select new { Id = c.TaskId, Marker = c.Marker });
```

And then seeing if the sequence is the same:

```
bool equals = curCombo.SequenceEqual(newCombo);
```

This works well, however if `plan.Combo` is null, I get an exception.  Unfortunately, I can't force this array to never be null.  There doesn't really seem to be a way to set `newCombo` to an *empty* array and still compare the two with `SequenceEqual`, and putting the whole thing is an `if` block to trap that condition seems rather messy.  I want a single, eloquent LINQ statement.

One thing I was thinking would be something like this:

```
var newCombo = (from c in plan.Combo ?? new TrainingPlanCombo[0] orderby c.TaskId select new { Id = c.TaskId, Marker = c.Marker });
```

However, this seems a little hacky.  Ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `plan.Combo` is null insteaf of an empty collection which is best practise.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Agreed.  But `plan.Combo` is deserialized from some JSON coming from the web browser, so it's tough to enforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to write an extension method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AssureNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    if (list == null) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    return list;
}
```

**EDIT**

Usage would be:

```
List<int> nullList = null;
var sum = nullList.AssureNotNull().Sum(); //will be 0
```

Comment: I actually kinda like this solution.  I *could* override the getter on `.Combo` to return an empty array, however I really don't like code that *assumes* something will never be null.

Comment: +1 @MikeChristensen: You don't need to change the getter, you only need to modify the query with this extension `... plan.Combo.AssureNotNull() ...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yea, I was saying I *prefer* this solution *over* changing my getter, as it makes the code more bulletproof.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [monads](https://github.com/sergun/monads.net/wiki/Monads-for-objects) in .net to achieve what you want:

```
var newCombo = plan.With(p=>p.Combo.OrderBy(c=>c.TaskId)
                                   .Select(c=>new { Id = c.TaskId, Marker = c.Marker }));

bool equals = newCombo.Returns(n=>n.SequenceEqual(curCombo), false);
```